# How to disable a Setting in the Settings Flyout (charms bar)

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I need to disable a setting in the settings flyout of my app. Is this possible?

**Details**

When the user opens the charms bar for my app and clicks on 'Settings' the app's `onsettings` event fires and I add commands like this:

```
e.detail.applicationcommands = {
    "aboutFlyout": { title: "About", href: "/settings/about/about.html" },
    "optionsFlyout": { title: "Options", href: "/settings/options/options.html" }
};
```

Now I need to disable or enable the "Options" setting depending on some internal app state. I specifically do not want to *hide* the setting entry so the user can always discover it's there.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no direct way of doing this.

You might have to create a new optionsDisabledFlyout.

```
if (condition)
{
   display the optionsFlyout option
}
else
{
  display the optionsDisabledFlyout
}
```

Set the value of settings.HeaderBrush for the optionsDisabledFlyout to grey to give the effect that it is disabled. And, make sure that your optionsDisabledFlyout doesn't launch a new page when invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(condition)
    e.detail.applicationcommands = {
        "aboutFlyout": { title: "About", href: "/settings/about/about.html" },
        "optionsFlyout": { title: "Options", href: "/settings/options/options.html" }
    };
else
    e.detail.applicationcommands = {
        "aboutFlyout": { title: "About", href: "/settings/about/about.html" },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't disable it. I get your point for discoverability of the options.

I think the best option is to leave the command like this and on the Options page show some message that the control is disabled due to the reason why it's disabled.

Another thing that comes to mind is leaving the href parameter empty? Not sure what happens than, but maybe just an hyperlink that doesn't do anything. (Also not user friendly)

Comment: Leaving the href empty is a good idea, unfortunately it throws: `throw new WinJS.ErrorFromName("WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.BadReference", strings.badReference);` The workaround is definitely something to consider if disabling is not possible.

Comment: Too bad, couldn't test it myself. Hopefully you'll find a way to disable it. But i'm a little worried because it's a system component.